# vue.js: ":class" cause the classList is wrong

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

as cood like this

```
'<div class="item" :class="{'editable':canEdit}"></div>';
```

1. set 'canEdit' to false    -------the classes of 'div' are "item"
2. '$("div").addClass("on")' ------the classes of 'div' are "item on"
3. set 'canEdit' to true      -------the classes of 'div' are "item editable"

---

**question:why the classes of 'div' are not "item on editable"**

Comment: Because when Vue re-renders the `<div>` it isn't aware of any classes that you've added externally.

Comment: Have you added jQuery? And what is the current status of classes? Tell me the class names which are applied.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not using Vue to add class to the element. So Vue doesn't know you have added a new class to the element.

See this example where I add a class NOT using Vue:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div ref="e" class="a" :class="{ b: b }"></div>
      <button @click="toggleB">Toggle B</button>
      <button @click="addC">Add C</button>
    </div>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      b: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleB(){
      this.b = !this.b;
    },
    addC(){
      this.$refs.e.classList.add('c');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.b {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.c {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Now if I use Vue to add class to it, it will work because now Vue knows:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div class="a" :class="{ b: b, c: c }"></div>
      <button @click="toggleB">Toggle B</button>
      <button @click="addC">Add C</button>
    </div>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      b: true,
      c: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleB(){
      this.b = !this.b;
    },
    addC(){
      this.c = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.b {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.c {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: thank you bro,but I can't use vue to add Class,because if I use vue to add Class,I should define a series of variable to maintain the status

Comment: @Perhaps that's exactly what you need to do. That's the philosophy behind Vue.